# THREE: Controls are not smooth due to lots of models

Tags: javascript, three.js, controls, 3dsmax

I am developing a room in threejs and there are lot of models like sofa, walls, floor, curtain, rug, table, wall-panel, etc. (all are 3ds max models). So my problem is the controls are not smooth, I have tried orbital as well firstPersonControls but all are getting janked while operating. Please help?

Comment: Do you mean your FPS is too low for a smooth rendering or that the camera movement is too rude with orbit & FP controls ? Do you have an example to link ?

Comment: 1/2 Hopefully i use to look my OS control panel when i open an unknown scene because you were going to crash my laptop if i didnt close it. What about a mobile visitor.. If you dont want this to happen to others you actually should remove the link :) @Master James was right your scene is too detailed : the TV should only be ~20 vertices, the lamp ~200, the floor should only be a plane. This is an advice for your app but as i surely dont have your kind of GPU i cant really answer your question, it depends on your computer : your FPS is probably low too. Also you should try trackballcontrols.

Comment: 2/2 If you want a scene to look realistic in webgl, and still visible for common desktop+mobile users here are some good pratices : no antialiasing, no shadow casting, draw VERY simple mesh (the goal only is to reproduce the main shape), draw the details and the shadows on the textures then resize + compress the textures. I remember a very good example of a webgl room interior designed like that and it was awesome,i dont have the link in mind. When i looked the models they were extremely simple and there wasnt any light : a shadowmap was merged with the texture and meshbasicmaterial was enough

Answer (score 0):

You should try to reduce the models details of the mesh in favor of providing details in the texture map images (bump map etc.).

Basically you can load initially low quality models and if the frame rate is still good (maybe 20 fps and up) start adding in the more detailed versions.

If it's really bad, notify them they should try it on a faster device or desktop.
If this is on your fast machine/device, then try one model at a time to isolate when or where there's something else going on that's wrong.

Otherwise I'm sure there's a handful of features to disable from double-sided to aliasing etc. Same with lights and shadows etc. Isolate the problem or reduce the models and features. Again you can do this optimization and problem analysis on lights and shadows too.